# Help identifying a song at the beginning of episode 1 of Your Lie in April

Tags: music, your-lie-in-april

What is the song that plays at the very beginning (before the OP) of the first episode in Your Lie in April? It's played in other episodes too and I can't find anything about it when I look it up.

Answer (score 1):

This is track #1 from disc #1 of [the OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/49046), titled "Kimi wa Wasurerareru no" (translates as "Could you forget?", which Kaori says to Kousei multiple times over the course of the show). Here is a 20-second extract from the beginning of the piece: https://clyp.it/2mfjovz4.